# Sum of nilpotent elements in a noncommutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

I've already proven that if $a, b$ are nilpotent and $ab = ba$ then $(a + b)$ is also nilpotent. But is the condition $ab = ba$ necessary? (Aluffi III.1.6.ii)

I've tried proving that, if $a, b$ are nilpotent and $(a + b)$ is nilpotent as well, then $ab = ba$, but without much success.

I've also tried to construct a counter-example where $a, b$ and $(a + b)$ are all nilpotent but $a, b$ do not commute (by playing around with a few matrices of size 2), but every time I managed to get $a, b$ such that $(a + b)$ is nilpotent, then I magically got $ab = ba$, and I don't know many other examples of non-commutative rings.

Also at this point I don't have a good intuition about this problem. So, do $a, b$ necessarily commute?

Comment: Incidentally, asking whether a hypothesis is "necessary" usually does not mean you're asking whether the converse holds, but whether the result remains true if you drop the hypothesis.  So I suspect what you're actually being asked here is whether $a+b$ must always be nilpotent if $a$ and $b$ are nilpotent, even if $ab\neq ba$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Let $k$ be a field. In $k^{3\times3}$, take$$a=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}\text{ and }b=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}.$$Then $a$, $b$, and $a+b$ are nilpotent. But $ab\neq ba$.

Comment: I wonder if a similar example can be constructed in $k^{2\times2}$ or I just should've been less lazy and considered bigger matrices.

Comment: I don't know whether such an example can be found in $k^{2\times2}$.

Comment: In $k^{2\times 2}$, if $a,b,a+b$ are nilpotent then $a^2 = b^2 = (a+b)^2 = 0$ so $ab=-ba$.  Not sure where to go from there.